# Typedef Enum - Instantiation at top module and port connection

Tags: module, enums, typedef, system-verilog, instantiation

I am trying to instantiate a state machine at top level module and connect the states at top level ports to probe them as part of debug. I am trying something like this as in example below:

```
 .state[0](DEBUG_1),
 .state[1](DEBUG_2),
```

`DEBUG_1` and `DEBUG_2` are output ports in the top level module, and I want to probe these signals at the top logic.

The above is not working in SystemVerilog and gives errors. How else can this be done?

---

```
      package states;

      typedef enum logic [2:0] {RE = 3'b000, 
                    NOR = 3'b001, 
                    WD = 3'b011,
                    TO = 3'b010,
                    EVL = 3'b110,
                    DEC = 3'b111} state_t;

       endpackage
```

---

```
     import states::*; 
     module fsm (
     input                   clk,                    
     input                   reset,
      output  state_t state
     );
```

---

```
    import rtl_pkg::*;
    import states::*; 
    module top (
    output   logic        DEBUG_1,                       
    output   logic        DEBUG_2                      
    );  

 fsm fsm_inst (
.clk(sys_clk),                    
.reset(sys_reset), 
.state[0](DEBUG_1),
.state[1](DEBUG_2),
.state[2](DEBUG_3),
);
```

---

```
 ERROR - (VERI-1137) syntax error near '['
 ERROR -  module top ignored due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get rid of the compile errors:

```
module top (
    output   logic        DEBUG_1,                       
    output   logic        DEBUG_2, DEBUG_3                      
);  

     // ... signal declarations

     fsm fsm_inst (
        .clk   (sys_clk),                    
        .reset (sys_reset), 
        .state ({DEBUG_3, DEBUG_2, DEBUG_1})
    );
endmodule
```

Concatenate the 3 `DEBUG` bits using `{}`, then connect it directly to the `state` port.